# Change UISearchBar magnify icon color and position

Tags: ios, swift, icons, uisearchbar, magnify

I have a UISearchBar and I would like to change the position of the initial magnify icon (the one that appears in the middle of the UISearchBar) as well as the color or icon.

So far I changed the tint and the icon image.

However, the new icon shows up only if I test the app on a simulator but on an actual device(both run iOS 9.3) it still shows the default icon.

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "SearchbarIcon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

As for the magnify icon position, I want it in the left side, where it shows up if I activate the UISearchBar.

[image]

[image]

I found quite a lot of answers around here many of the provided solutions don't work on iOS 8.0+ or are in Objective-C and I am having some problems understanding them.

I tried to add a custom background containing the icon but it shows up at the bottom of the search bar while the icon is still there:

[image]

The background shows up OK if I change the background offset for Y to -44 (the height of the UISearchBar) but I can no longer type since it seems the entire text field is pushed up. I also tried to change the vertical offset for the SearchText to 44 to compensate but no luck. To be honest, I am not sure what Search Text and the Background offsets are supposed to do but I decided to give them a try.

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the position of the search bar icon using

```
func positionAdjustmentForSearchBarIcon(_ icon: UISearchBarIcon) -> UIOffset
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/positionAdjustmentForSearchBarIcon:

Comment: Thanks. But as far as I understand this changes the position of the icon that shows up when you start typing, not of the initial search icon. Something like this. self.srcRegimenSearchBar.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search) I am interested in changing the position of the icon in the middle of the searchbar.

Comment: Ah, I see. Right, well, in the past, when UISearchBar was much less configurable, I interjected my own code by iterating through it's subviews and finding the UITextField that it contains and becoming it's delegate. That gives you access to a lot of positioning callbacks. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW29

Comment: OP is wrong. This will change the offset of the subviews of the searchBar even when being inactive. And thanks for this, Michael. It's my first time knowing this thing. :D Helped me a lot.

Comment: Yeah this is the right way to do it. Swift 5 version example:

searchController.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0), for: UISearchBar.Icon.search)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
uiSearchBar.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset, for: UISearchBar.Icon)
```

replace `UIOffset` with your desired offset value `UIOffset(horizontal: CGFloatvertical: CGFloat)` and `UISearchBar.Icon` with `.search`

Answer (score 2):

@Michael - Thanks for all the help. 
I managed to grab the UISearchBar's UITextField:

```
func customizeSearchBar()
{
    for subview in srcRegimenSearchBar.subviews
    {
        for view in subview.subviews
        {
            if let searchField = view as? UITextField
            {
                let imageView = UIImageView()
                let image = UIImage(named: "SearchBarIcon.png")

                imageView.image = image;
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

                /*imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 20, 19)*/

                searchField.leftView = imageView
                searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to change the position since I have access to the frame but it seems only the the top and height can be modified, at least the way I tried so I set the height and width to 0 (I couldn't find a way to make it nil or remove it completely) and I added an UIImageView with the new icon over in the left side of the UISearchbar and added a custom horizontal offset for the tint.

Not the best solution out there, I'm sure of it, but for now it works.

[image]

[image]