# UISearchBar magnifying glass icon goes outside searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

When searchbar is in inactive state and the placeholder is too big, the magnifying glass icon goes outside the searchbar. Anyone knows how to fix this? Nothing
[image]

```
     lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.autocorrectionType = .yes
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchBar.placeholder = ChangeToLanguage(SEARCH_LABEL_PLACEHOLDER_SEARCHMODULES)
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        let searchBarTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        searchBarTextField?.tintColor = GlobalTintColor
        searchBar.barTintColor = GlobalTintColor
        return searchBar
    }()
```

Comment: so you want to put image as placeholder in UITextField?

Comment: No. It's a string which is too big for the searchbar to hold. So it truncates it. But also pushes the magnifying glass icon outside.

Answer (score -1):

Try adjusting the position of search bar icon by grabbing the `UITextField` attached to `UISearchBar` as mentioned in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36594565/2740582